# using events in private blockchain raises leveldb not found error

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events, leveldb, web3js-v1.x

i'm getting `{ [Error: Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"leveldb: not found"}]` when trying to use events on a private eth blockhain.

What might be the problem? (I've installed Leveldb with brew)

Thanks

```
myContract_ws.events.ContractCreated({
    fromBlock: 0,
}, function(error, event){ console.log("EVENTS log: ",event); })
.on('data', function(event){
    console.log("EVENTS ONDATA",event); // same results as the optional callback above
})
.on('changed', function(event){
    console.log("ContractCreated / CHANGED",event);
})
.on('error',function(err){
  console.log("ERROR HERE");
  console.log(err);
  console.error;

});
```

geth: 1.8.21-stable
web3: 1.0.0-beta.41
macOsX 10.13.6